# JQplot hide serie by clicking on its legend name : tooltip always displayed

Tags: jquery, graph, jqplot

I am using JQPlot with [legend plugin](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-enhancedLegendRenderer-js.html) to toggle series displaying by clicking on its legends names.

```
    legend: {
        show: true,
        placement: 'outsideGrid',
        renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer
    }
```

It is working, but the serie tooltip is always displayed when the serie is hidden. It is an issue if you have plenty of series and you want hide all but one : all tooltip of the hidden series are displayed on mouse over.

Here is a fiddle to explain the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/Bouillou/WdLnm/284/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced this bug a while back. See my post on the jqPlot Google group:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/jqplot-users/nickw/jqplot-users/PShgGTuXpeg/m3NPzEIWRscJ

Essentially, the code is checking to see if each line is visible before raising an event. The problem is that the visibility is not being dealt with correctly on the Javascript side (the CSS is fine), hence the issue you are seeing where a hidden series is still deemed visible.

My solution was to set `s.show = s.canvas._elem.is(':hidden');` in the `Series.prototype.toggleDisplay` method.

This appears to have been resolved since version 1.0.4r1120 - try updating to a more recent version to see if that helps.

Comment: You are right, the last version is no longer bugged. Thanks for your time